# Order results by count with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that stores a list of tags. I would like to be able to write a script that displays the tags a user uses the most. But, I am having trouble with writing the MySQL query to do so.

Table Structure:

```
tag_id | user_id | tag
--------------------------------
1      | 1       | hiking   
2      | 1       | fishing
3      | 1       | hiking   
4      | 1       | swimming
5      | 1       | hiking   
6      | 1       | swimming
```

What I have so far just outputs all of the tags:

```
$query= "SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE user_id='1'";
```

I would like the results to look like this:

```
hiking
swimming
fishing
```

Can I use an order by "Count" or something to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to order by `COUNT`

Try this:

```
SELECT tag 
  FROM tags
 GROUP BY tag
 ORDER BY COUNT(tag) DESC
```

Output:

```
╔══════════╗
║   TAG    ║
╠══════════╣
║ hiking   ║
║ swimming ║
║ fishing  ║
╚══════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a249d/13)

#### Update:

You can show counts like this:

```
SELECT tag
      ,COUNT(tag) AS `COUNT`
  FROM tags
 GROUP BY tag
 ORDER BY COUNT(tag) DESC
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a249d/12)

Comment: Now, is there a way to still group the tags, but order them alphabetically?

Comment: I think you need to `DESC` to order by it in descending as OP want's.

Comment: The only problem with your fiddle, is that it seems to order them by Count ASC instead of DESC, how do I fix that?

Comment: @user2320500 - I have updated the fiddle already. Click on the fiddle once again.

Comment: How do I display the groups?

Comment: @user2320500 - *How do I echo this out in PHP?* That should be a different question. Before you ask it please search it.

Comment: @user2320500 - You mean you want to display count also? [Like this?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a249d/11)

Comment: @hims056 Yes, I would like to display the count as well!

Answer (score 0):

yes as per your latest comment see my below solution to work out.

```
SELECT tag FROM tags
                     GROUP BY tag
                                  ORDER BY tag ASC,COUNT(tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

just like what hims suggested just add , count(*) to the tag column name

> SELECT tag, count(*) FROM tags GROUP BY tag ORDER BY COUNT(tag) DESC